# How do I add Facebook Test page to a Facebook App?

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook app and I created a Test User (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users) then created a test page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-pages). I configured a webook callback URL with it. With a regular user and regular page, I add the page to the app, I was assuming that this should the case too for the test page but I cannot (logged in using my personal FB account). So in turn, when I send a message as the test user, I do not get the message in my service.

Am I missing anything? I also was trying to add my account to the test page as admin but I couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Found this article and it solved my issue:

https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/230322797329131/?disable_redirect=0

But there's a correction. This snippet should have &subscribed_fields=messages

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/subscribed_apps?method=POST&&access_token=